# Is it possible to change the size of a fixed text to image code?

Tags: html

First of all, excuse my poor wording of the question. Still a novice.

I'm dealing with a packing slip template that's html based and I was asked if I can make the barcode bigger. I don't have access to the barcode itself, all I can do is call it by typing *gnShortBarcode* (calling *barcode* gives me a longer version of the barcode and they don't use that one.) I tried putting it in a div and making the entire div bigger and that didn't work. Is it even possible? Just to reiterate, the code looks something like `<p> _gnShortBarcode_ </p>` which is why it's so weird to me. it not calling a class or anything where I can re-adjust the barcode dimensions myself.

I appreciate any sort of help given. Even as simple as helping me re-wording the question for future purposes. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: You'll need to inspect the HTML element generated by `_gnShortBarcode_` after it has been printed to the DOM. Try right clicking the barcode on a modern browser and selecting "inspect element". Click and hover elements until you find the one that is the barcode (likely an image). Check if the image has a unique CSS class name. You can change the style for this element in your local CSS

Comment: I believe that's precisely it! I inspected it and while the image didn't contain a class, the file path for it was in /classes/bcode and after testing that in css..... it would've worked but the html editor automatically comments that piece of code out. I guess I have to reach out to them and contact them to do it from their end rather than mine. Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: if the image doesn't contain a class name, maybe the parent or parent of parent does? You can always style it using a CSS "path" `.parent_class_name img {}`

Comment: I think it would've worked if i was allowed to style at all. The problem at hand is that whenever i add any styling, it gets commented out once i save. So this is a thing where i have to talk to them internally. Thank you very much for your input though! Being so new, I need to incorporate inspecting more into my troubleshooting.